# Post to facebook wall using API Graph and missing share button

Tags: facebook, post, button, share

Is it possible to post a message with share button in Graph API. I use SDK-PHP v3 and this code:

```
    $args = array(
        'access_token' => TOKEN_HERE,
        'message'   => 'message here',
        'link'      => 'http://www.example.com/',
        'caption'   => 'caption here'
    );
    $result = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $args);
```

It works fine but share button is missing. There is a comment and like button but no SHARE button. Please do not give me any links to tutorials or fecebook documentation. If you know how to do this or you know it's not possible just write it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, I found solution. maybe someone will be interested. to add a link with share button you have to use 'me/links' instead of 'me/feed'.

```
$attachment = array(
    'access_token'=>TOKEN_HERE,
    'message'=>'message_here',
    'link' => 'http://www.example.com/',
);

$result = $facebook->api(
    'me/links',
    'post',
    $attachment
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isnt a complete replacement as Facebook ignores the description, title and picture parameters when using this method. Please subscribe to the bug report if you are interested in seeing this fixed: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194522957295380

Comment: Is their option to share links to friends feed using this code          $result = $facebook->api(
    'me/links',
    'post',
    $attachment
); Instead of me using friends id...

Answer (score 0):

Note that using /links instead of /feed also applies to posting to the wall on a Facebook page  - a share button (link) isn't there if you use /feed and does appear if you use /links. The Facebook API documentation is in the "Publishing" section [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). For those interested, the Ruby/Rails looks something like this:

```
   ## Put together the content of the post to the FB page 
   data = {
      :message      => 'Your message here',
      :link         => 'http://www.example.com/your/own/page/link/here',
      :picture      => 'http://www.example.com/your/own/image/link/here',
      :name         => 'Your post name or title here',
      :caption      => 'Your caption here',
      :description  => 'Your description here'    
    }
    ## Start a new HTTPClient
    client = HTTPClient.new()
    ## Define the URI for posting to Facebook
    url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/<FB PAGE ID HERE>/links?access_token=<FB PAGE ACCESS TOKEN HERE>'
    ## POST the message to Facebook
    msgpost = client.post(url, data)
    ## Get the results of the post (in JSON)
    msgpostresults = JSON.parse(msgpost.body)
```

Hope that's some help to someone....