# how to add share action to the post in facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm using this code to post to my application wall

```
$attachment = array('message' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...',
            'name' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'caption' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'link' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'description' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'picture' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Download!',
                              'link' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))
            );

$result = $facebook->api('/2222222222222/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

when i post to my application wall manually the post is appearing on the application users wall with the share action 
but when i use the above code it only appear on the app wall with like and comment actions only.
why?
and how to add the share action to the actions array?

Answer (score 1):

i didn't find any answer online, but i just found the solution to my problem by chance
i removed the action parameter from the attachment.

but if there is a link parameter in the attachment the share action won't appear so you will have to give up the link parameter.

Answer (score 0):

the proper names for the action link is:
array( array('text' => 'Download!', 'href' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));

Keep in mind that you can't use action links in the graph api (yet). so this functionality is limited to the REST api.

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=270

This article explains it. The key is this:

```
'actions' => array('name'=>'Sweet FA','link'=>'http://www.facebookanswers.co.uk'),
```

This is fine for adding one action. However, I'm not sure how to add two.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: There is no way to add multiple actions at the moment for anyone that comes across this. The answer is to simple use the one-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143932/post-to-facebook-wall-using-api-graph-and-missing-share-button) 
instead of

```
$result = $facebook->api('/2222222222222/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

use

```
$result = $facebook->api('/2222222222222/links/','post',$attachment);
```

i'm still facing one little problem with the picture not showing after this change, if i come to a solution to it I'll come back here and post it.