# Facebook PHP API post link to Fan Page / News Feed not showing sharing action anymore

Tags: php, facebook, share

I'm using the Facebook PHP Api to post links to fan pages and user news feeds. All of this works 100%. Recently, I discovered that my "Share" action in posts aren't there anymore. I've only got "Like" and "Comment".

Could anyone please help me get the "Share" link back or alternatively point me in the right direction of using the "actions" argument to get that up and running again?

Thanking you all in advance,

Comment: Just an update, the posts from my application shows in the user's timeline but not in their news feed anymore. This used to be on both. Maybe the two are related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some extensive research and trolling the net like a mad man, I found the solution.

[Post to facebook wall using API Graph and missing share button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143932/post-to-facebook-wall-using-api-graph-and-missing-share-button)

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/335325956484296

In a nutshell :

When posting to facebook ('/me/feed', 'POST', ...) the share link will not be visible, but when posting to ('/me/links', 'POST', ...) the share link will be visible. Keep your post details exactly the same just change the 'feed' to 'links' and the share button will be visible.

Really hope that this could safe someone else a lot of headaches as well!

Comment: Just saved me hours of extensive research and trolling the net like a mad man.

Comment: Your answer also fix a bug I had when posting a link to a page as a page (with a page access token): if I post the link to /feed, it appears in "Recent post by others" with the user name, whereas if I post the link to /links as you suggested, it appears on the page timeline with the page name. So yeah, you also saved me a huge headache, thanks!