# posting on a pages wall using api is not giving share button

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to share a post on a page's wall using facebook api. everything works perfect . but the share button is not coming next to like and comment.

here is my code

```
$message_body = array(
                    'access_token' =>Yii::app()->session['page_access_token'],
                'message' => $message,
                'actions' => array(
                 array(
                    'name' => Yii::t('UserController', ' Get details '),
                    'link' => Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl ('user/adminmoreaboutprovider?&postId='.$fbPostId ),

                    ),
                    ),
                    );

$facebook->api("/".$userpage."/feed","post",$message_body);
```

Any idea how to bring share link there ?

Comment: Try posting to "/".$userpage."/links

Comment: then i got this error (#100) The parameter link is required

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143932/post-to-facebook-wall-using-api-graph-and-missing-share-button

Comment: yes. but i dont have a link to share ..so in that case what can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$msg_body = array(
        'message' => $message,
        'actions' => array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'Get details',
                                'link' =>  Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('user/adminmoreaboutprovider?&postId='.$fbPostId ),
                            )
                        )
    ); 
 $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/6creeks/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $msg_body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);  //to suppress the curl output 
$result= curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close ($ch);
```

This gave me share lin but the get details links is missing on the Page wall. Is there any way to get both of this together?

Answer (score 0):

With curl you can make a post (yes, along with the share button) using the following command.

```
curl -F 'access_token=XXXX' -F 'message=test' https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE NAME]/feed
```

Hope this can be used as is in PHP.